# Function to tell if a is a power of b. Which is more accurate?

Tags: python, recursion, boolean

I have the following two implementations for determining whether `a` is a power of `b`. The second one is my own code, but the book I'm following gives the first code.

I asked AI bots, but they also prefer the first code.

Why is the first one considered more accurate than mine? Both give the same answers...

#### First code:

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if a % b != 0:
        return False
    if a == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return is_power(a//b,b)
```

#### Second code:

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if a % b != 0:
        return False
    if a//b == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return is_power(a//b,b)
```

Comment: The book gives such a wrong code?

Comment: @Barmar At least the second code mostly works, the first doesn't.

Comment: thank you @Michael Butscher , for your answer , but can you elaborate it a little more, my tiny brain can't process this answer.

Comment: (1) If we have positive integers, the floor division `a//b` would result in 0 if `a < b` and in 2 or larger if `a >= b * 2`, therefore `2 * b > a >= b`. (2) The line `if a//b == 1` can only be reached if first if-condition `a % b != 0` is wrong, therefore `a % b == 0` which means `a` is a multiple of `b`: `a in [b, 2 * b, 3 * b, ...]`. In combination with (1), only `a == b` is possible.

Comment: side note.  avoid recursive functions (even though text books show them). `for` and `while` loops are nearly always more efficient...

Comment: What do you mean with "more accurate"? (Especially since you say they give the same answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write:

> ... both gives the same answer

They actually don't. For instance, for arguments `a=2, b=2`, the first returns False, the second True.

But: neither works correctly.

- Both return False for `is_power(1, 2)`, yet 2⁰ = 1.
- Both get into an infinite loop for `is_power(2, 1)` and for `is_power(0, 1)`. They should return False.
- Both produce a division-by-zero error when the second argument is 0, yet 0 is a power of 0 (using any strictly positive exponent)

Using the same recursive pattern, using `power//base`, here is a corrected version for *signed* integer arguments:

```
def is_power(power, base):
    def recur(power):
        if abs(power) < 2 or power % base:
            return power == 1
        return recur(power//base)

    if abs(base) < 2:
        return power in (1, base)
    return recur(power)
```

Comment: `is_power(0**0, 0)` returns `False`

Comment: Ah yes, the one case that mathematicians call undefined. Updated my answer. Thanks, @Kelly!

Comment: Well, [looks like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) some of them do define it (as 1).